# /usr/bin/time: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, time, command, fedora

I'm trying to run the time command for a file on a virtual machine running Fedora 19 64-bit and I get the message "/usr/bin/time: No such file or directory". I tried googling, but it appears it's something that I should already have. How do I get this on my computer?

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, make sure you mark it as the accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 22):

For those on a raspberry pi or similar debian-based distributions, I found that I could install the package `time` (`sudo apt install time`) to obtain access to the `time` command.

Edit: For Fedora-based systems, the package name might be different. Try a `dnf search time`, followed by a `sudo dnf install {package_name}`. I don't have a Fedora machine immediately to hand to  get the exact package name from.

Comment: On my Ubuntu machine I was able to install time only after running `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: "dnf install time" worked for me on rocky9.

Answer (score 1):

bash/zsh/modern shells usually implement a basic `time` command as a builtin. So it won't exist on the filesystem, but `time mycommand` should work.

If you want the "proper" time command (with more options eg: `-l`/`-v`), then you'll need to install it via apt/yum/etc. You'll need to run it as `/usr/bin/time mycommand` so the shell-builtin doesn't get invoked.

Answer (score 0):

It might be in other locations. I'd start by typing:

```
which time
```

This command will give you the path to time, if it's anywhere in your path.

If you need to build it yourself, you can get the source here:

http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Time

Comment: I downloaded it and followed the instructions in the INSTALL file, but I got an error: 
"/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file 'usr/local/bin/time': Permission denied 
make: *** [install-binPrograms] Error 1"

I also tried running the "which time" command, but the output was "which: no time in " followed by a directory in parenthesis.

Comment: Your system administrator seems to have blocked you from installing. Install with *sudo* if you can. Otherwise, you're going to need to contact your sysadmin to give you permissions to do this.

Comment: But, would it be the same than `/usr/bin/time`? Referencing [this answer to one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28167965/3692177), at least in Debian-based distros, `/usr/bin/time` is not exactly the same than the `time` available in environment PATH...