# Get real-time machine usage data while running commands

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose as an example that I want to run some script in a terminal (or some command/snippet that I just hardcoded into it). **I wonder if it exists a tool for analyzing live statistics of machine usage** (% CPU, execution speed, dedicated memory, etc.) **which I can pipe my script into or something like that**, so I can obtain this data in the output just after the script's output.

I've had no luck searching in Google, neither in SO questions. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

**EDIT:** Using the manual indications, I tried up this way:

```
:~$ time -f "CPU %P%%\nMax RAM %M\n" ./myscript.sh
-f: command not found
/*
  normal output
*/
:~$
```

also tried:

```
:~$ time --format="CPU %P%%\nMax RAM %M\n" ./myscript.sh
--format: command not found
/*
  normal output
*/
:~$
```

also, as a desperate measure:

```
:~$ time --verbose ./myscript.sh
--verbose: command not found
/*
  normal output
*/
:~$
```

Nothing works. I don't understand why args are rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `/usr/bin/time`  or simpler version built-in bash `time`

Comment: Cool! Done for execution speed. Thank you :). Now just % CPU load and dedicated memory are left.

Comment: /usr/bin/time is a lot more versatile. @SebasSBM look at the man page for it, you can get the memory and cpu using the format.string.http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html

Comment: @JID Very interesting... I'm trying it out now to tweak the output, but for some reason `-f` and `--format` args are rejected with a _"no command found"_ response. I'll make an edit to show what I tried.

Comment: @SebasSBM To be clear `time` and `usr/bin/time` are completely different. `usr/bin/time` is an external app whereas time is a bash builtin. To change the format for `time`(builtin) you would need to change the `TIMEFORMAT` environment variable. The man page i linked was for `usr/bin/time`.

Answer (score 2):

time -p sh script_name

O/p

real 13.37
user 0.00
sys 0.82

Answer (score 0):

Here I leave the results obtained thanks to the help offered by @mefju and @Poo, long ago:

Using the external app `/usr/bin/time` instead (which is not the same than the bash builtin `time`, as JID explained above) solved the args rejection. This way it works well for me:

```
:~$ /usr/bin/time -f "CPU: %P\nMax RAM: %M kB\nTime: %e s\nSwap cnt: %W" ./myscript.sh
```

The resulting output:

```
CPU: 63%
Max RAM: 1432 kB
Time: 0.45 s
Swap cnt: 0
```